# Linux rename multiple files that are not in utf-8

Tags: linux, bash, character, rename

I have old samba server files that does not show special characters like ä,ö,ü,õ in file names. They are showed as ? mark. Because of that my clients cannot open those files or folders. They see the files and folders, but their names are blank. In server they are showed like this: T??tunnid.doc for example.

Once I rename them with `mv` command, then my clients can open the folders and files with no problems.

Does anyone know any script that I can use to rename all the files that have ? mark in them. So they show - instead. I would like to rename the files in specific folder for example /samba/documents/...

Comment: maybe `rename` can help?

Comment: I have looked in to rename. As I know of it only finds and renames specific extension files. Like if I wanted to rename .doc files etc. But there are folders, docs, images etc etc. So something like 
if name includes ? then replace with - (i know this is not a code so just for example.)

Comment: check [rename man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/prename.1.html)

Comment: I have doubt what it samba problem. It similar to wrong `mount` options. Check your `fstab`

Comment: It was not samba's problem. It was the encoding of the old server. Even rsync change encoding option did not work for them. Now there are over 2000 files that need renaming so I do not want to do it manually.

Comment: Windows users see your characters correctly, but Linux users wrong?

Comment: No the windows users do not see the file name at all. It shows that the file or directory exists on server but they can not open it, the name is empty, but in linux I see it as T??tunnid for example

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `convmv` which rename files changing it character encoding. Usually this symbols `?` says about different encoding of filenames and terminal/filesystem/something else. Try to determine which character encoding your files use and run it like this:

```
convmv -fcp1251 -tutf8 *
```

You can write simple script or just shell loop to iterate over directories and rename all needed files:

```
find /full/path -execdir convmv --notest -fcp1251 -tutf8 {} \;
```

But first **be sure** you use correct character encoding.

Comment: If I understand is right it worked correctly and had broken recently. So problem in recent actions.

Comment: It did work correctly when it was on their old server. Once we took over the administration and replaced the server with a better one and rsync'ed those files it was messed up.

Comment: Their encoding is binary :S

Comment: What do you mean by 'binary encoding'? I tell about filenames, not files itself.

Comment: Do you use `mount` before pump files from old server?

Comment: Emm??? Mount for what? It was done over network via rsync. I did not need to mount anything. Everything was mounted already.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that this will work, so I would like some conformation.

```
find . -type d -name '*?*' -execdir rename '?' '_' {} \;
```

Comment: It will not work. Question mark tells that this symbol cannot be displayed, many symbols can be showed like this.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the rename command and I think it would work

```
rename "s/[^A-Za-z0-9-_]/_/g"
```

But how can I add a directory to it. So it only checks that directory not the whole ubuntu.